# Getting  the value of chronometer as displayed in View 

Tags: android, time, chronometer

I'm using chronometer to display the time in my android application.

i want to get the chronometer value that is displayed in the screen. i tried to use

```
int stoppedMilliseconds = 0;
          String chronoText = chronometer.getText().toString();
          String array[] = chronoText.split(":");
          if (array.length == 2) {
            stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 1000
                + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 1000;
          } else if (array.length == 3) {
            stoppedMilliseconds = Integer.parseInt(array[0]) * 60 * 60 * 1000 
                + Integer.parseInt(array[1]) * 60 * 1000
                + Integer.parseInt(array[2]) * 1000;
          }
          chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - stoppedMilliseconds);
```

and to get the value i used `long elapsedMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();`

it displays a certain number like that for me it does not look like the time that is displayed on the screen. if the timer on the screen shows 1 sec, i want to get the value exact 1sec and not any random numbers.

is there anyone that can help me with this?